# iterating over list of string and combining string values Python

Tags: python, string, list, bit

I have a list of strings, like so:

```
    sixbit = ['000011', '000001', '010100', '100001']
```

I would like to iterate over this list and generate a new one that looks like this:

```
    eightbit = ['00001100', '00010101', '00100001']
```

For the purposes of illustration, len(sixbit) equals 4, because that translates nicely into eightbit. Ideally sixbit could be of any length -- it's fine if eightbit "cuts off" any remaining 1s or 0s.

Here is some code I've tried...sadly, it's **way off** but maybe you could see what I'm trying to do. The idea is 1) put all digits into one big string 2) loop over each digit and keep count, collecting digits into holder as you iterate 3) when count = 8 append to list 4) continue iterating

```
def compress_six_bit(ary):
    final_list = []
    holder = ''
    temp_string = ''
    encode_counter = 0

    for i in ary:
        holder = holder + i
        while encode_counter < 8:
            encode_counter = encode_counter + 1
            temp_string = temp_string + i
            final_list.append(temp_string)
        encode_counter = 0
        temp_string = ''

    return final_list
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
>>> chained = itertools.chain.from_iterable(sixbit)
>>> [''.join(bits) for bits in itertools.izip(*[chained]*8)]
['00001100', '00010101', '00100001']
```

### Explanation

`chained` is just an iterator of all the letters of the original strings. It uses [`chained`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) function from `itertools`.

```
>>> chained = itertools.chain.from_iterable(sixbit)
>>> list(chained)
['0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1']
```

`[chained]*8` creates list containing **the same** `chained` object 8 times.

`*` just unpacks those 8 elements into [`izip`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip) parameters.

[`izip`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip) just return tuples, the first one of which contains the first letters  of each chained iterator in the parameters, the second tuple contains second letters, etc. There are 8 chained objects, so there are 8 letters in each tuple.

Most importantly, the letters are taken from each iterator, but it is in fact 8 instances of the same iterator. And it is consumed by each call. So the first tuple contains the first 8 letters of the chained iterator.

```
>>> chained = itertools.chain.from_iterable(sixbit)
>>> list(itertools.izip(*[chained]*8))
[('0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '0', '0'), ('0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '1'), ('0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1')]
```

At the last step, we join them in list comprehension:

```
>>> chained = itertools.chain.from_iterable(sixbit)
>>> [''.join(bits) for bits in itertools.izip(*[chained]*8)]
['00001100', '00010101', '00100001']
```

Comment: Thank you ovgolovin!! A lot of great answers here, but I felt yours was the most descriptive/detailed. Thank God for the StackOverflow community, hopefully one day I can answer some questions on this thing!

Comment: One slight issue: if I changed sixbit to equal something other than just 4 instances of binary numbers -- this doesn't seem to work. Is there any way to deal with that?

Comment: nevermind! stupid mistake. I was testing different values for sixbit and didn't reassign chained, and as a result got an empty list when I called [''.join(bits) for bits in itertools.izip(*[chained]*8)]. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> [''.join(sixbit)[bit:bit + 8] for bit in range(0, len(sixbit) * 6, 8)]
    ['00001100', '00010101', '00100001']
```

In words: for `bit` from `0` to total number of bits, in increments of 8, take bits `bit` to `bit + 8` from the joined bitstring.

Answer (score 2):

```
from itertools import *

def flatten(listOfLists): 
  "Flatten one level of nesting" 
  return chain.from_iterable(listOfLists) 

def grouper(n, iterable, fillvalue=None): 
  "Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks" 
  # grouper(3, 'ABCDEFG', 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx 
  args = [iter(iterable)] * n 
  return izip_longest(fillvalue=fillvalue, *args) 

[''.join(a) for a in grouper(8, flatten(sixbit))]
=> ['00001100', '00010101', '00100001']
```

Answer (score 1):

So, I think the goal is to combine the first list into one string, then split that string into three eight character strings.

```
sixbit = ['000011', '000001', '010100', '100001']
# Combine the first list into one string
tmp = "".join(sixbit)
# Split that string into three eight character strings
eightbit = [tmp[i:i+8] # get 8 characters from tmp, starting at position i
            for i in range(0, len(tmp), 8)] # For each multiple of 8 (0, 8, 16..)
```